# Incorporating CEFPython into Kivy App on Mac -- keyboard input doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, chromium-embedded, cefpython

I'm attempting to run the simple Kivy application located [here](https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/source/browse/cefpython/cef3/linux/binaries_64bit/kivy_.py) on OSX.

At first, CEF failed during initialization. The output was:

```
igskcicgltgm047:Kivy_Test dslosky$ kivy cefTest4.py 
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/.kivy/logs/kivy_15-07-09_18.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 173 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <2.1 NVIDIA-10.2.1 310.41.15f01>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <NVIDIA Corporation>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M OpenGL Engine>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <1.20>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[CEF Python] Initialize() called
[CEF Python] CefExecuteProcess(): exitCode = -1
[CEF Python] CefInitialize()
2015-07-09 12:20:09.283 python[4355:122290] Internals of CFAllocator not known; out-of-memory failures via CFAllocator will not result in termination. http://crbug.com/45650
[CEF Python] App_OnBeforeCommandLineProcessing_BrowserProcess()
[CEF Python] Command line string for the browser process:  --browser-subprocess-path=/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cefpython3/subprocess --lang=en-US --log-file=debug.log --log-severity=info --enable-release-dcheck --resources-dir-path=/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cefpython3 --locales-dir-path=/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cefpython3/locales --remote-debugging-port=51420 --no-sandbox
[0709/122009:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(269)] locale_file_path.empty()
[0709/122009:FATAL:main_delegate.cc(449)] Check failed: !loaded_locale.empty(). Locale could not be found for en-US
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I found a discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cefpython/VkXEUGbTBmw) that suggested manually setting the `local_pak` flag to avoid this error. I made the following changes to the example code starting on line 150:

```
# Command line switches set programmatically
g_switches = {
    "locale_pak": cefpython.GetModuleDirectory()
    +"/Resources/en.lproj/locale.pak",
    }

#init CEF
cefpython.Initialize(settings, g_switches)
```

This solved my initialization issue! The CEF Browser appears, but will not respond to any input from my keyboard. I am also unable to scroll using my trackpad, although I am able to use it to click links.

I gave the whole background on this issue in case I took the wrong route by changing the `locale_pak` flag.

I'm using:

```
Kivy v1.9.0  
Python v2.7.6  
cefpython3 v31.2
```

I should also mention that I am able to run the `wxpython.py` example that is packaged with `cefpython3` without issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in the kivy_.py example key codes were translated specifically for Linux only, see the translate_to_cef_keycode() function:

https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/source/browse/cefpython/cef3/linux/binaries_64bit/kivy_.py?r=5cf79c6eec11#355

Support for Windows/OSX key codes needs yet to be added.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Czarek. Do you know a work around for this? Or do you know of a Kivy/CEFPython example that runs on Mac? Also, do you know why the wxPython example doesn't require keycodes?

Comment: @dslosky the workaround is to work on translation codes, it should be an hour of work. The wxpython example runs in windowed mode and all is taken care of automatically. Kivy runs in OSR mode and requires the step of sending key events to CEF by calling SendKeyEvent.

Comment: @dslosky Add a print statement in that function and go through all the keys on your keyboard to see what's the code. If you make that work please send a patch in the cefpython issue tracker.